# Porque al hacer una peticion GET a una base de datos y guardar los datos en una variable Object.keys() no devuelve las llaves

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, json, base-de-datos

queria saber porque razón cuando hago un json de prueba, tipo:

```js
let test = {'Carlos': 1, 'Elias': 2}
```

Y lo envio a una función para crear un grafico de barras con canvas, que por cierto, seguí exactamente los pasos de [este tutoria](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-draw-bar-charts-using-javascript-and-html5-canvas--cms-28561). Cuando lo hago con los datos de prueba me funciona muy bien, el resultado es algo como el siguiente:

[image: datos de prueba]

Pero cuando uso los datos de la bd si me retorna los datos, pero cuando envio el json no encuentra las llaves del json, esté es el código con el que agrego los datos:

```js
data.response.forEach(voto => {
    Nombre = voto.Nombre.split(" ")[0];
    Nombre.toString();
    votos[`'${Nombre}'`] = voto.Votos;
    console.log(votos);
});
```

Deduje que el error era porque cuando creo el array de pruebas las llaves están entre comilla, pero no creo que afecte realmente, solo intente hacer algo por probar, elcódigo original solo agregaba el nombre sin las comillas, `votos[Nombre] = voto.Votos`

El resultado que obtengo de eso es esto, teniendo en cuenta que agregué una condición, si las llaves son menor a 1 dibuja lo siguiente:

[image: pueba con la bd]

Y no logro solucionar el error, en consola me tira:

```
Uncaught TypeError: myChart.draw is not a function
```

Que es mi función para hacer todo de la grafica, pero se que es porque directamente, no existe ```
keys.lenght`, la sección que se encarga de eso es esta:

```js
let keys = Object.keys(this.options.data);
```

Pero me devuelve `{}` cuando consigo los datos de la bd, y me devuelve `{Carlos: 1, Elias: 2}` cuando es la prueba, finalmente, mi código sql es el siguiente:

```sql
SELECT candidatos.Nombre, COUNT(votaciones.Id_Votacion) AS Votos FROM candidatos, votaciones WHERE candidatos.Id_Candidato = votaciones.Id_Candidato GROUP BY candidatos.Id_Candidato
```

No es la gran cosa, me devuelve un diccionario como este, `{'Nombre': 'Carlos Antonio Rodrigez Bazques', 'Votos': 1}`, por cada usuario y luego lo agrego al json en js.

myChar, barChar es identico al de el tutorial que segí:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(votos).length; i++) {
                colors.push(randomColor());
            }
            let myChart = new barChar({
                canvas: myCanvas,
                data: votos,
                padding: 25,
                gridScale: 20,
                gridColor: "#B9B6B6",
                colors: colors
            });
```

Manjo la bd con python, y esté es el código en python:

```py
#Dentro de una lase cru() que maneja las consultas
def mostrar_votos(self):
        try:
            cursor = self.conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
            sql = "SELECT candidatos.Nombre, COUNT(votaciones.Id_Votacion) AS Votos FROM candidatos, votaciones WHERE candidatos.Id_Candidato = votaciones.Id_Candidato GROUP BY candidatos.Id_Candidato"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            return result
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            return {'status':'error', 'msg': 'No se pudieron encontrar los votos', 'code': str(err), 'votos':{}}

#Dentro de la clase del servidor, en do_GET:
class Handler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        elif self.path == '/mostrar_votos':
            response = curd.mostrar_votos()
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(json.dumps(dict(response=response)).encode('utf-8'))
```

Y así llamo al la funcion desde js:

```
$.get("http://localhost:8000/mostrar_votos", (data)=>{
                console.log(data);
                data.response.forEach(voto => {
                    Nombre = voto.Nombre.split(" ")[0];
                    //Combertir el nombre a string
                    Nombre.toString();
                    votos[`'${Nombre}'`] = voto.Votos;
                    console.log(votos);
                });
            }, 'json');
            #Hice una prueba imprimiendo las llaves, y me devuelve [], y si imprimo solo votos si imprime el json normal.
            console.log(Object.keys(votos))
        }
```

Alguna idea de como lo soluciono?

Comment: Podrías mostrar dónde instancias tu objeto `myChart`? `Uncaught TypeError: myChart.draw is not a function` se refiere a que estás tratando de hacer `.draw()` en un objeto indefinido

Comment: Ok, actualizare la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en cómo manejas la asincronía de `$.get()`. Como `$.get()` es asincrónico (en este caso, tiene como interfaz una [`Promesa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)) este permite que se pase a la siguiente línea de código sin necesariamente haber ejecutado la función que se le entrega para procesar la respuesta.

Es por eso que el `console.log(Object.keys(votos))` viene vacío, pues el callback de `$.get()` aún no se ejecuta.

Asegúrate de instanciar los objetos `new barChart(...)` luego de que tu petición se haya completado.

```javascript
$.get("http://localhost:8000/mostrar_votos", (data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    data.response.forEach(voto => {
        Nombre = voto.Nombre.split(" ")[0];
        //Combertir el nombre a string
        Nombre.toString();
        votos[`'${Nombre}'`] = voto.Votos;
        console.log(votos);
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(votos).length; i++) {
        colors.push(randomColor());
    }
    let myChart = new barChar({
        canvas: myCanvas,
        data: votos,
        padding: 25,
        gridScale: 20,
        gridColor: "#B9B6B6",
        colors: colors
    });
    myChart.draw()
}, 'json');
```

sino, puedes usar `$.ajax(...)` con `async: false` para que se ejecute sincrónicamente:

```javascript
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/mostrar_votos',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: (data)=>{
        // Esto se ejecutará antes de continuar a la siguiente línea del $.ajax(...)
        console.log(data);
        data.response.forEach(voto => {
            Nombre = voto.Nombre.split(" ")[0];
            //Combertir el nombre a string
            Nombre.toString();
            votos[`'${Nombre}'`] = voto.Votos;
            console.log(votos);
        });
    }
});
// Ahora debería mostrar 'votos' con las llaves.
console.log(Object.keys(votos))
```

Ojo que este último modo no es compatible con `dataType: 'json'` ni con *Cross-Domain Request*. Lo que te podría traer problemas a futuro.

Comment: muchas gracias, con la primer solución se arreglo, además agredeco la explicación para tenerlo en cuenta en adelante.

Answer (score 1):

Con que lenguaje manejas la BD.
en cuanto al codigo creo que deberias almacenar la respuesta json en una variable:

```
var r = data.response
r.forEach(voto => {
Nombre = voto.Nombre.split(" ")[0];
Nombre.toString();
votos[`'${Nombre}'`] = voto.Votos;
console.log(votos);
```

});

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias por el consejo, y manejo mi BD con python

Comment: bueno yo uso `php` pero como tu código parece `javascript`, creo te funcionará. Yo he trabajado mucho con  `json` y `ajax` pero no me he topado con ese ese error.

Comment: Lastimosamente no me finciono :(

Comment: revisaste que todo lo que reciba de la BD se envie en formato `json`